# Has the Kickr Core had multiple versions?

Tags: trainer, turbo-trainer

The Wahoo *Kickr Core* was released in 2018. The *Kickr* has had [5 generations](https://zwiftinsider.com/wahoo-kickr-versions/) so far. Has the *Kickr Core* had any new generations and if so, how does one identify the differences?

Like any new tech, the first versions have problems. I'm trying to avoid those when buying used. Alternatively, I'll buy new.

Comment: The Core is a kickr V4 with different feet (+ not foldable), see https://www.dcrainmaker.com/2018/09/wahoo-kickr-core-trainer-in-depth-review-2.html In this sense it is not a first version. Btw I share the concern for first versions lacking user feedback.